# LASSO Regression with noise

Tags: machine-learning, least-squares, lasso, regularization, fitting

I know LASSO regression is useful to exclude redundant features, so can it be useful when you have noisy data?

I explain better with this example: Suppose I generated a data set using an equation (e.g y = x^2 + x + 3). So if I build a matrix containing different functions (x, x^2, x^3, sin(X), ...) and apply a regression to find their coefficients, I would hope to find those terms I used in the generation phase (only x, x^2 are non-zero).

Now, if I add noise to data before applying the regression, I will find new non-zero terms due to the noise (Least Square fit tries to minimize cost function using all predictors) but those terms weren't in my equation!

So my idea is to use LASSO Regression to reduce the number of terms and I should find only those who where in the equation. Does it sound logical?

Comment: Yes, you can use LASSO or subset selection (full or stepwise). If you are interested in recovering the true data generating process, consider adaptive LASSO or subset selection using BIC.

Comment: Thank you very much!